# How do I instantiate a gameObject with one out of various classes inside a script?

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, struct, instantiation

I'm trying to instantiate a gameObject (Player) that has a class in a script. The thing is that this script has a struct for the variables and several classes that assign those variables with an Awake according to the class.

I have no idea how to spawn the gameObject with just one of those classes.

I did the script with all the parameters but now Im lost about using just one class out of the others

It says Enemy and Player but what im talking about is different enemy classes, anyways its still the same code.

```
    //CLASES DE ENEMIGOS

public class Enemy_Default : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Enemy enemyDefault;
    public Entity_SpriteManager spriteManager;

        private void Awake()
        {
            enemyDefault.healthPoints = 1500;
            enemyDefault.defense = 0;
            enemyDefault.damage = 10;
            enemyDefault.artifactDamage = 0;
            enemyDefault.critical = 0;
            enemyDefault.penetration = 0;
            enemyDefault.atqSpeed = 100;
            enemyDefault.spriteEnemigo = spriteManager.GetEnemySprite("Enemy_Default");
        }
 }



//CLASES DE PERSONAJES

public class Character_DPS_Default : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Character characterDefault;
    public Entity_SpriteManager spriteManager;

        private void Awake()
        {
            characterDefault.healthPoints = 800 + (800 * (0.05f * characterDefault.pnHP));
            characterDefault.defense = 0 + characterDefault.pnDEF;
            characterDefault.damage = 10 + characterDefault.pnDMG;
            characterDefault.artifactDamage = 0 + characterDefault.pnARDMG;
            characterDefault.critical = 0 + characterDefault.pnCRIT;
            characterDefault.penetration = 0 + characterDefault.pnPEN;
            characterDefault.atqSpeed = 100 + characterDefault.pnATSPEED;
            characterDefault.spriteCharacter = spriteManager.GetCharacterSprite("Character_Default");

                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it would be easier to undestand if you show your code. It's not clear what you mean with this struct and how it interacts with other scripts

Answer (score 0):

Your current code would help illuminate a lot, but this is my guess based off what you've stated so far.

In the PlayerScript, create an Initialize() method. Move all the code out of Awake into that and have Awake call Initialize()

Then in your instantiate player script:

```
GameObject playerPrefab;
Instantiate(playerPrefab, startingVector, Quaternion.Identity);
PlayerScript player = playerPrefab.GetComponent<PlayerScript>();
player.Initialize();
```

Or if you don't have the PlayerScript on the prefab:

```
PlayerScript player = playerPrefab.AddComponent(typeof(PlayerScript)) as PlayerScript;
player.Initialize();
```

Comment: But if I have an Awakes for every class?

Comment: It sounds like you are asking: "I have multiple components all with Awake, but I only want to run the Awake from one of the components" -- is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, like

class enemy1
{
Awake()
}

class enemy2
{
Awake()
}

All in the same script

Comment: Ah, looks like this approach is not going to fly as the moment you run:

Instantiate(playerPrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);

All the scripts are enabled and Awake is called immediately.

The next approach would be to not have any of the scripts on the Prefab, instantiate it and then use:

    GameObject player = Instantiate(playerPrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
    if (isPlayer)
    {
        player.AddComponent<PlayerScript>();
    }